# PHP create function with FetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

i'm trying to develop an open-source project but i've got some issues.
I'm using a PHP function file where all my functions are written. It contains this : 
*functions.php*

```
<?php include 'inc/db.php';
function getCategories(){
$sqlGetCategories = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM categories");
$sqlGetCategories->execute();
return $sqlGetCategories->fetchAll();
}
?>
```

And this is my *index.php*

```
<?php include 'inc/functions.php';
$listeCategories = getCategories();
foreach($listeCategories as $row) {
    echo "<option>"; echo $row['name']; echo "</option>";
}?>
```

When I call the function *getCategories* nothing shows up on the screen.

I tried a lot of another ways found on this site, nothing worked properly.

If you guys could help me it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: `$conn` is undefined. You can use `$conn` as global variable or pass it as a parameter in your functions or better still just use a class with a constructor

Comment: @Akintunde it's probably there inside db.php

Comment: @CodeIt that would not make it visible in the function's scope

Comment: @CodeIt no it is not there. OP has a function. No way `$conn` will work. Read more on variable scopes

Comment: This is my db.php file that contains *conn*

`<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "hosts";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection to database failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
`

Comment: Have you debugged the code within the getCategories() function? Does it return what it is supped to? Btw, if there is no input parameter in a query, then there is no point using a prepared statement.

Comment: Yep, $conn should be declared as global $conn.

Comment: @lezogeek For debugging try =`print_r($sqlGetCategories->fetchAll())` inside the getCategories fn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the variable `$conn` does not exist as you now have a function declared. You will need to pass your connection variable either as a parameter or as a global variable in your function. If you just had a php file which gets the categories from your database without the use of a function, then you wouldnt't face the problems of variable scopes

**OPTION1:**

```
<?php 
include 'inc/db.php';
    function getCategories($conn){//pass connection as a parameter
    $sqlGetCategories = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM categories");
    $sqlGetCategories->execute();//returns true/false
    return $sqlGetCategories->fetchAll();
    }
?>
```

OR:

**OPTION2:**

```
<?php
include 'inc/db.php';
    function getCategories(){
    global $conn;//use as a global variable(Although i prefer option1)
            $sqlGetCategories = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM categories");
            $sqlGetCategories->execute();
            return $sqlGetCategories->fetchAll();
            }

            ?>
```

Read more on variable scopes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: My pleasure though